# Disable modules in Metasploit Pro

Tags: exploit, metasploit

I have been using Metasploit pro for last few days. I understand that exploiting in Pro version is automatic using exploit ranks(GUI). But If I want to disable certain modules while exploiting, is it possible to disable?

This is required when certain exploits are not supposed to be performed on production servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed with the support team. There is no way you can disable the modules in Metasploit Pro. You can only choose the ranking of the exploit modules. I also confirmed that there are no Denial of Service modules used with "Great" or "Excellent" ranking modules.